# How to determine if a value falls within a specific angle range on a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm attempting to pick random colors from a specific range on the HSL color wheel.  What is the best way to determine if an angular value falls within an angular range on a circle when that range crosses over the $360/0°$ point of the circle?

For example, if I needed to pick a random value between $355°$ and $5°$. So 1 would be an acceptable value in this example, but 180 would not.

Is there an easier/more elegant way to do this other than checking if the value is between $355-360°$ and $0-5°$?

Comment: If this is part of a computer program then I think you want clarity more than elegance. So just check whether the range crosses the circle at $360/0$ and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood the question: you want to generate an angle between two angles. You can do it by cases: let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the minimum and maximum angles. Let also $\alpha' = \alpha MOD 360$ and $\beta' = \beta MOD 360$. If $\alpha' \lt \beta'$ you just generate a number between the two, otherwise, call $\beta'' = \beta'+360$ (which will be greater than $\alpha'$) and generate a random number between $\alpha'$ and $\beta''$, call it $\gamma$ and then your random angle is $\gamma' = \gamma MOD 360$.

Just a note: in almost all programming languages there is the MOD operator (in C is %) which is used exactly the same as the division, except it returns the remainder of the division. This way you get a random integral angle between two given integral angles.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, is this correct?  If $\alpha = 355°$ and $\beta = 45°$, then $\beta + 360 = 715$.  A random angle between $45°$ and $715°$ could be $695°$ which is equivalent to $335° mod 360$.  This isn't in the range $355-45°$.

Comment: In your case $\beta + 360 = 405$, not $715$, so you choose an angle between $355$ and $405$. Although I admit I have not done any proofs of correctness, I find it intuitively correct because if $\beta < \alpha$ I simply translate $\alpha$ up, and then bring the entire arc back to the range [0,360].

Comment: Yeah, I mixed up my variables.  Thank you for your answer!